# Initialize Boost shared_ptr in constructor

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I have a class, which has a`boost::asio::io_service` object. I want this object stored in a `boost::shared_ptr`.

So my header looks like this ( I got rid of any unnecessary code so it doesn't distract )

```
class CommandDispatcher
{
private:
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> m_ioservice;
public:
    CommandDispatcher();
};
```

When I now create an object of `CommandDispatcher`I want that an `io_service` object to be initialized for the pointer. Now I'm not quite sure how to do this. I looked up two differentsolutions but only one is working and I'm not quite sure if it's a nice one. But see for yourself:

```
CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher()
{
    m_ioservice.reset(new boost::asio::io_service);            // this actually works
    //m_ioservice = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>
    //    (new boost::asio::io_service);                     // this doesn't work
}
```

So the `reset` call is working, but  I think this one is actually to reassign the pointer. So it is *not wrong* to use it but it doesn't seem like the nicest solution to me.
 The suggestion for the `make_shared` call I found in another question. But this one just won't work for me ( I implemented it as described in the official boost example ). I get

`/usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp:189: error: invalid conversion from ‘boost::asio::io_service*’ to ‘size_t’`

`/usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/make_shared.hpp:189: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘boost::asio::io_service::io_service(size_t)’`

I'm not quite sure how to do this now, which would be the best way ( maybe there is a complete other option to do it ). Or maybe I'm doin it right, but I'm gettin something with the `io_service`wrong.

Hope this question hasn't been already here in this way ( I looked up some old question, but no answer seemed to fit for me ).

Comment: Why are private variables listed before the public methods? Surely the public interface is more important than private implementation details? :) </nit-picking>

Comment: Well I actually thought( and learned some time ago ) that it's "good tone" to first declare public and private member variables and then declare public and private methods.

Comment: I think that most people would be more interested in the public interface, as opposed to what variables you use to achieve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher()
   : m_ioservice(new boost::asio::io_service) // ver 1. this is how you should do it.
{
    //m_ioservice.reset(new boost::asio::io_service); // ver 2    
    //m_ioservice = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>(); // ver 3
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works ( and seems nice ) but what I'm not understanding is where the difference between this call is and `m_ioservice = new boost::asio::io_service` which actually doesn't work???

Comment: Haha sorry for formulating it a bit vague. If u say `CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher() : m_ioservice(new boost::asio::io_service)` isn't that the same as sayin `CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher() { m_ioservice = new boost::asio::io_service; }` ?

Comment: Google, C++ initialization list, e.g. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/

Comment: @Toby: `m_ioservice(new io_service)` is using the explicit `shared_ptr` constructor that takes a raw pointer. `m_ioservice = new io_service` won't work because there's neither an assignment operator nor a non-explicit constructor taking a raw pointer; you have to either use `reset`, or explicitly create a `shared_ptr` to assign.

Comment: +1 for different versions, and indication of correct way to do it as a suggestion. You may need ver 2 in that case: Lets assume you need class A to instantiate class B & you have to do something before you instantiate class A. By the way, I also tried ver 3, it says boost does not have make_shared func, should I include something?

Answer (score 8):

If you're using `make_shared`, then you don't use `new` yourself; you pass it the constructor arguments, and it will create the object for you. In this case, there are not arguments, so just do:

```
m_ioservice = boost::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>();
```

although it would be nicer to initialise it in the initialiser list rather than the constructor body:

```
CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher() : 
    m_ioservice(boost::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>())
{
}
```

Using `make_shared` has the advantage that it will only perform a single memory allocation, while initialisation using `new boost::asio::io_service` will require two (one for the object, and one for the shared reference count).

Answer (score 1):

The *nice* way is probably

```
CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher() : 
  m_ioservice(new boost::asio::io_service)
{
}
```

because the alternative has you default-constructing the `shared_ptr` first, and then reassigning it.

Or, equivalently using `make_shared`:

```
CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher() : 
  m_ioservice(boost::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>())
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways :

- for simple initialization, create in the constructor's list :

.

```
CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher() :
  m_ioservice( new boost::asio::io_service )
{
}
```

- for dependency injection using a factory :

.

```
CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher() :
  m_ioservice( Factory::Create() )
{
}
```

- for dependency injection using by passing already created object :

.

```
CommandDispatcher::CommandDispatcher( boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > service ) :
  m_ioservice( service )
{
}
```